# Python input that ends without showing a newline

Tags: python, newline, textinput

Is there an python function similar to raw_input but that doesn't show a newline when you press enter. For example, when you press enter in a Forth prompt it doesn't show a newline.
**Edit:**
If I use the code:

```
data = raw_input('Prompt: ')
print data
```

than the output could be:

```
Prompt: Hello
Hello
```

because it printed a newline when I pressed enter. I want a function similar to raw_input that doesn't show the newline. So if the function I wanted was called special_input and I used the code:

```
data = special_input('Prompt: ')
print data
```

than the output would be something like:

```
Prompt: Hello Hello
```

Comment: I'm not sure about raw_input, but the print function won't include a newline if you use a comma after e.g ( print "Hello",)

Comment: In Python versions under 3, print isn't a function, it's a keyword, so adding a comma changes things because it has a special syntax. raw_input is a function, so it doesn't have a special syntax that a keyword can have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print in Python without newline or space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are other ways to read a line like `raw_input`

You can use [`sys.stdin()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdin):

```
import sys
line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Or if you want to get a password you can also use [`getpass.getpass()`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html):

```
import getpass
line = getpass.getpass()
```

But if you want something more fancy you will need to use [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html)