# How to keep updating values for a period of time instead of iterating and printing it over and over again python

Tags: python

So currently I have the following code:

```
for x in range(10):
   print(f'Machine1 Busy Value  :  {read_log ("machine1_busy_val"):.2f')
   print(f'Machine2 Busy Value  :  {read_log ("machine2_busy_val"):.2f')
   print(f'Machine3 Busy Value  :  {read_log ("machine3_busy_val"):.2f')
   print(f'Machine4 Busy Value  :  {read_log ("machine4_busy_val"):.2f')
```

This is giving me out that like

```
   Machine1 Busy Value  :  Value
   Machine2 Busy Value  :  Value
   Machine3 Busy Value  :  Value
   Machine4 Busy Value  :  Value
```

and this is being printed 10 times with different values as the code goes through the loop.

I need the value to update without "Machine1 Busy Value" and others being printed again. I want those to be printed once and the value for them to keep updating for a period of time. How would I go about implementing that change?

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the printed display in-place?

Comment: Yes exactly I want the value to updated instead of everything being printed over and over again

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can do it for the last printed line only. I don't think you can do it for multiple lines without refreshing the entire display.

Comment: Hopefully this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300770/how-to-refresh-the-multi-line-output-dynamically

Comment: Actually it looks like that reprint package can update multiple lines — good find!